# tinyMCE inside hidden div updates only first time and becomes readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a grid and div with tinyMCE (textarea) in it on my page.
Div is initially hidden. After populating textarea:

```
$('#editor').val(data.Content);
$("#divGrid").hide("slide");
$("#divCard").show("slide");
InitMCE();
```

Content in tinyMCE appears and component is editable but, after hidding div with textarea (#divCard), populating again  `$('#editor').val(data.Content);`
tinyMCE  appears readonly and content is not shown.

in function InitMCE() is code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   mode: "textareas",
   theme: "advanced",
...
});
```

I tried with

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, '#editor');
$('#editor').val(data.Content);
$("#divGrid").hide("slide");
$("#divCard").show("slide");
InitMCE();
```

and with:

```
tinyMCE.remove($('textarea'));
$('#editor').val(data.Content);
$("#divGrid").hide("slide");
$("#divCard").show("slide");
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, '#editor');
InitMCE();
```

and some other variations but no success.

Comment: You cannot hide textarea if you want tinymce to work

Comment: well its a horrible thing in that case

Comment: why do you need to hide it? TinyMCE hides it automatically

Comment: in that div #divCard i have some buttons and other textboxes

Comment: you can move textarea to some other div

Comment: not possible, I need to show whole div with all contolls and textarea together in same div at the moment when I get data after click a row on grid.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you hiding the textarea.

If you inspect the html DOM struture after TinyMCE is initialized, you will see that TinyMCE uses div and span infront of `textarea` to render your text, but when you try to edit it, you are actually editing the textarea.

So if you hide your textarea, you won't be able to edit it anymore.

Comment: I'm hidding a div with textarea in it. not textarea itself

Comment: but that will effectiviely hide the textarea

Answer (score 0):

There are several problem that may arise when the source html element (in your case a textarea) is hidden on editor initialization.
Tinymce will take care of hiding the former textarea.
The solution to your problem will be to set the textarea visible just before initialization - then you will have no problem editing its contents afterwards.

Comment: As you can see in code I posted, div wich contains textarea is everytime set to show before tinyMCE.init but it helps only first time.

$("#divCard").show("slide");
InitMCE();

Is there any other way to destroy Tinymce then tinyMCE.remove($('textarea'));?

Comment: yes, you may (and should) shut down the tinymce instance before initializing a second one with the same id: tinymce.execCommand('mveRemoveControl', false,'your_editor_id');

Comment: already tried - doesn't work...

tinyMCE.execCommand('mveRemoveControl', false, '#editor');
            tinyMCE.init({

Comment: use tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'mydiv'); not mveRemoveControl

Comment: is your example live or can you create a tinymce fiddle with this?

Comment: you can see an example at http://test.biomed-systems.com/

user: stack
pass: stack

Comment: thx for the example. the solution to this is to call tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'editor'); if the user clicks on "back to grid" or any other action that will change the page.After the user gets back to the list with different entires to choose from there is still an editor object active ( console.log(tinymce.editors))  and reinitializing another edtior with the same id yields to the current result.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but would you like to check did I understand you well? I'v placed destroyer in $("#lnkBack").click(function (e) after visibility of divs changed but its still same result for me.
Is InitMCE() function on the right place?

Comment: i tried to shut down tinymce using my javscript console, but it did not work!!! i ve never seen this before. you will have to use 'editor' instead of '#editor'. another aproch could be to dynamically change the textarea id before initialization - you could give that a try

Comment: if '#editor' is changed to 'editor' error NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation] appears.

Yes I should look for some other approach, thank you very much kind sir

Comment: as i said before you could try to use a counter and add the actual counter to the textarea id before the tinymce editor init

Comment: The funny thing is that it doesn't work even with id changing.
I placed IncreaseID(); just before tinyMCE.init and nothing... 
If you are interested you may see that online.
It's really weird.